# How can I make this work and is there a way to optimize this?

Tags: c++, optimization, switch-statement

I wanted to do a calculator with c++, and I did not wish my calculator to do only 2 number calculations, so I "made" 2 operator calculator. Also, I want to learn if there is a way to make this without two switch statements to make it easier for machines and programmers to read.

```
#include <iostream>

int top1 ;

int main()
{
    char operatr1, operatr2;
    float num1, num2, num3, num4 ;

    std::cout << "Please choose the first operator ( +, -, *, /):";
    std::cin >> operatr1 ;
    
    std::cout << "Please choose the second operator ( +, -, *, /):";
    std::cin >> operatr2;

    std::cout << "Please enter three numbers: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    switch (operatr1) {

    case '+':
        int top1{ num1 + num2 };
    
        break;

    case '-':
        int top1{ num1 - num2 };

        break;

    case '*':
        int top1{ num1 * num2 };

        break;
        
    case '/':
        int top1{ num1 / num2 };

        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Error! The operator is not correct" << std::endl << "The operators are ( +, -, *, / ).";
    
        break;
    
    }

    switch (operatr2) {

    case '+':
        int top2{ top1 + num3 };
        std::cout << "The answer is:" << " " << top2;
        break;

    case '-':
        int top2{ top1 - num3 };
        std::cout << "The answer is:" << " " << top2;

        break;

    case '*':
        int top2{ top1 * num3 };
        std::cout << "The answer is:" << " " << top2;

        break;

    case '/':
        int top2{ top1 / num3 };
        std::cout << "The answer is:" << " " << top2;

        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Error! The operator is not correct" << std::endl << "The operators are ( +, -, *, / ).";

        break;

    }

}
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: I know it's a bad practice to use a global variable but I couldn't get the second part of the switch to "see" the top1 variable.

Comment: All the issues can be answered by Google.  Part of learning to code is working through easy stuff like this on your own

Comment: The downside of Google is until you know enough about a language to detect morons and frauds, you're gonna learn C++ from a lot of morons and frauds. You're a lot better off with [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to get started.

Comment: BTW, the local variables you declare in the `case` statements will disappear after execution leaves the `case` statement.  Try changing `int top1{` to `int top1 = {`.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ shunting yard algorithm" to get a calculator that can handle operator precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a function:

```
int Evaluate(const char operator,
             const int  num1,
             const int  num2)
{
    bool is_valid_operator = true;
    int result = 0;
    switch (operator)
    {
        case '+':
            result = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            result = num1 - num2;
            break;
        case '/':
            //  Note: integer division.
            result = num1 / num2;
            break;
        case '*':
            result = num1 * num2;
            break;
        default:
            result = 0;
            is_valid_operator = false;
            break;
    }
    if (is_valid_operator)
    {
        std::cout << "Result of " << num1 << " " << operator << " " << num2 << "\n";
        std::cout << result << "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your main would be simplified to:

```
//...
int top1 = Evaluate(operatr1, num1, num2);
int top2 = Evaluate(operatr2, top1, num3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `top1` outside the switch statement. The global `top1` you define doesn't have the value you expect, because you define a new `top1` inside each `case` statement. Your compiler should be warning you about this (actually, I think this should be an error in this case).

Further, since `num1` through `num4` are floats, your `top1` and `top2` should really also be `float`s, not `int`s

Effectively, remove `int top1` from your global variables, then in your main:

```
float top1 = 0;
switch ( operatr1 ) {
    case '+':
        top1 = num1 + num2;
        break;
    // ... continue with other cases here
}
```

Then, for your second `switch` statement, `top1` will be visible and have the correct value.

Comment: thank you for helping instead of scolding me like the others.

Comment: Another optimization is to extract the `switch` statements to a separate function.  Thus the `main` will make two function calls to one set of statements.